# Can the set of all limit points $E'$ that closes a set $E$ contain more than just limit points?

Tags: real-analysis

> **Definition:** If $X$ is a metric space and $E\subseteq X$, if $E'$ denotes the set of all limit points of $E$ in $X$, the **closure** of $E$ is the set $\overline{E}=E\cup E'$.
>
> **Question:** Can the set of all limit points $E'$ that closes a set $E$ contain more than just limit points?

In finding the closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, I consider the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. I know that every rational number is between two real numbers, so taking neighbourhoods centered at a rational number will always contain irrational numbers which are not in $\mathbb{Q}$. Is it more appropriate to say that the set of all limit points is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R-Q}$?

Comment: So you're asking if every rational number is a limit point of $\mathbb Q?$

Comment: Note that $\frac 1n\to 0$

Comment: A set of limit points by definition contains only limit points. What else would "set of limit points" mean? Are you asking whether something can be a member of both E and E'? "I know that every rational number is between two real numbers" What you need to show is that every two real numbers have a rational number  between them.

Answer (score 2):

Taken literally, your question does not make sense: $E'$ is by definition the set of all limit points of $E$, so it consists of the limit points of $E$, and nothing else.

From your example, I think you are confused about the definition of a limit point.  A limit point of $E$ is just any point $x\in X$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point of $E$ other than $x$ (this may not be the definition you have learned, as there are several equivalent definitions).  It is entirely possible that such a point $x$ is itself an element of $E$.  The set $E'$ contains *all* the limit points, not just the ones that "need" to be added to $E$ since they are not already in $E$.

So for instance, in the case $E=\mathbb{Q}$ and $X=\mathbb{R}$, $E'$ is $\mathbb{R}$, not just $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.  This is because if $x$ is any real number (rational or not), every open interval around $x$ contains a rational number different from $x$.